# События внутри ифрейма

Tags: jquery

Как определить то, что пользователь нажал на кнопку, которая находится в ифрейме? На своем же домене.

```
$('iframe#frameImg').contents().$('#imgUpl').on('click', function () {
    alert('!');
});
```

<iframe name="uploadImg" src="/" id="frameImg">

Сам ифрейм

```
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="ImgForm">
<input type="button" value="Add" id="imgUpl">
</form>
```

Но почему то не работает... Если установить на самой странице сифреймом, то срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('iframe#frameImg').load(function(){
    $(this).contents().$('#imgUpl').on('click', function () {
        alert('!');
    });
});
```

а так?

Comment: не помогло

Comment: почему вы думаете, что этот код:

    $(this).contents().$('#imgUpl')...

вообще валидный?

Comment: @rimlin: .find('#imgUpl')

Comment: не помогло

Comment: @rimlin что значит не помогло?  $(this).contents().find('#imgUpl')... вы так делали?

Comment: Да, так и делал

 $('iframe#frameImg').load(function(){
    $(this).contents().find('#imgUpl').on('click', function () {
        alert('!');
    });
 });

Comment: У меня работает: http://jsfiddle.net/D8Qkp/5/

Comment: Хм.. понятно, спасибо, буду смотреть у себя